# Android Room dao return null crash

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to implement offline first app by returning local data to UI before fetching remote data.

Here's my code

**Repository**

```
val trip: LiveData<DomainTrip> = Transformations.map(database.tripDao.getTrip(tripId)) {
    it.asDomainModel()
}

suspend fun refreshTrip(token: String) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val trip = webservice.getTrip(tripId, "Bearer $token").await()
        database.tripDao.insertAll(trip.asDatabaseModel())
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
interface TripDao {
    @Query("select * from databasetrip WHERE _id = :id")
    fun getTrip(id: String): LiveData<DatabaseTrip>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(trip: DatabaseTrip)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val tripRepository = TripRepository(getDatabase(application), tripId)
var trip = tripRepository.trip
```

If the user is opening a trip that is already stored in the database, above code works without any problem. `it.asDomainModel()` gets called as soon as user opens that trip. `it.asDomainModel()` gets called again as soon as that trip is retrieved from remote and saved into the database.

My problem is, if user is opening a trip that is not in the database, above code crashes when `it.asDomainModel()` is called the first time, with null pointer exception on `it`.

What confuses me more is that if above code were applied to this dao query

```
@Query("select * from databasetripinfo")
fun getTrips(): LiveData<List<DatabaseTripInfo>>
```

i won't get any null pointers exception on both call of `it.asDomainModel()` even when my database is empty.

Can somebody please help me? How do I avoid null pointer exception on `it.asDomainModel()` when database does not have that record?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all OK. If there is no item with the given id, the live data will return null. You can check for nullity before mapping in the transformation (`it?.asDomainModel`)

However for lists you will get empty list instead of null (it's a convention).